# The program has exited with code 2147516551 (0x80008087)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a solution that was compiling and running fine in Visual Studio 2022.  I added another project to the same solution, did some work on the new project and then checked it all into Devops.  Now, everything compiles fine.  I can "publish" to a folder and get the EXE and it runs.  But I CAN'T run it in Visual Studio or by trying to run the EXE in the bin folder structure.  When I click the run button in VS, I get:

> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.

> The program '[21684] Enable Instant Book.exe' has exited with code 2147516551 (0x80008087).

Now, this is a Winforms application targeting .Net 6.0 on Windows.  So I'm not sure why it's suddenly throwing this error nor why it says "CoreCLR" in the error when I'm not targeting Core.  I'm so frustrated with it that I'm thinking of dumping it all and redoing it in VS 2019 with .Net 4.x. But I thought I would see if any of you knew some magic to get it to return to a working state first.

Some of the things I've tried:

1. Clean and rebuild
2. Remove all projects except the very first one that I know was working and rebuild
3. Close and reopen VS / Reboot PC
4. Delete everything in "bin" folder and rebuild
5. Changing the compile from "Any CPU" to x64

Any ideas?

Comment: Right-Click your project and got to properties. Check if you selected a core framework under Application>General>Target framework.

Comment: Check https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/host-error-codes.md about this error.
Also please check if there is any useful information in the Output pane.

Comment: The Target Framework is .Net 6.0.
Output Type: Windows Application
Target Framework .Net 6.0
Target OS: Windows

The entire output of the output window is as quoted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same issue and resolved it, but not sure if that's the same root cause as yours.

For my case, I removed each package and eventually found the issue is from one package. The package indirectly references Microsoft.NETCore.App (can find that by checking .deps.json), which references Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR, and I guess that's not compatible with .NET 5+.

I resolved this issue by updating the package that references Microsoft.NETCore.App to latest version, which fortunately exists and no longer references it. There are several package version conflicts after it that need to manually resolve though.